# Event Handling in JavaScript with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I created a map using Google Maps API and I added two buttons on it. I'm trying to add,

var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();

trafficLayer.setMap(map); event on click. But it didn't work. Can anyone help me with that?

Here is the code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Harita</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }



  #panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }

</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
 // Home SetHome olayı başlangıcı 
//var map;
var deniz = new google.maps.LatLng(41.04052016955172,29.02639389038086);






     HomeControl.prototype.home_ = null;

     HomeControl.prototype.getHome = function() {
    return this.home_;
    }

    HomeControl.prototype.setHome = function(home) {
    this.home_ = home;
    }

    function HomeControl(controlDiv, map, home) {

    var control = this;

    control.home_ = home;

    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

     var goHomeUI = document.createElement('div');
     goHomeUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';


 goHomeUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  goHomeUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';



 goHomeUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  goHomeUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  goHomeUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
  controlDiv.appendChild(goHomeUI);

  var goHomeText = document.createElement('div');
  goHomeText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  goHomeText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  goHomeText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  goHomeText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  goHomeText.innerHTML = '<b>Home</b>';
  goHomeUI.appendChild(goHomeText);

  var setHomeUI = document.createElement('div');
  setHomeUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  setHomeUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  setHomeUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  setHomeUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  setHomeUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  setHomeUI.title = 'Click to set Home to the current center';
  controlDiv.appendChild(setHomeUI);

  var setHomeText = document.createElement('div');
  setHomeText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  setHomeText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  setHomeText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  setHomeText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  setHomeText.innerHTML = '<b>Set Home</b>';
  setHomeUI.appendChild(setHomeText);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(goHomeUI, 'click', function() {
    var currentHome = control.getHome();
    map.setCenter(currentHome);
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(setHomeUI, 'click', function() {
    var newHome = map.getCenter();
    control.setHome(newHome);
  });
}

function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: deniz
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

  var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map, deniz);

  homeControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);
  // Home SetHome olayı bitişi 

    //1. Marker   (ışık üni )
  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.16973837959339,29.561526775360107);
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng1,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

    // 2. Marker ( itü fef) 
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.106438353246574,29.023251682519913);
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng2,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });
        // 3. Marker ( ist üni )
  var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.01275461356736,28.9611903950572);
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng3,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

        //4. Marker ( marmara üni )
  var myLatlng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.98696866267149,29.052727818489075);
  var marker4= new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng4,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

  // 1. markerin  click -zoom olayı 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(11);
    map.setCenter(marker1.getPosition());
   });
  //2. markerin click- zoom olayı 
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(11);
    map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());
  });

  //3. markerin click- zoom olayı 
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(11);
    map.setCenter(marker3.getPosition());
  });

  //4. markerin click- zoom olayı 
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(11);
    map.setCenter(marker4.getPosition());
  });


  //1 . Marker için Bilgi Penceresi 
    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
       '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Işık Üniversitesi Şile Kampüsü</b> <br>'+ 
      'Meşrutiyet Köyü <br>'+
      'Üniversite Sokak, Dış Kapı No:2<br> '+
      '34980 Şile/İstanbul<br>'+
      'Santral: (0-216) 712 14 60 <br> '+
      'Faks:    (0-216) 712 14 68 <br>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker1);
  });

//2 . Marker için Bilgi Penceresi 
    var contentString2 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
       '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>İTÜ Ayazağa Kampüsü</b> <br>'+ 
'34469 Maslak - Sarıyer - İSTANBUL<br>'+
      'Telefon: 0 (212) 285 66 77  <br> '+
      '         0 (212) 285 66 79<br> '+
      'Faks: 0 (212) 285 65 95 <br>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString2
  });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    infowindow2.open(map,marker2);
  });

    //3. Marker için Bilgi Penceresi 
    var contentString3 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
       '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>İstanbul Üniversitesi Beyazıt Yerleşkesi</b> <br>'+ 

      '34452 Beyazıt, İstanbul – Türkiye<br>'+
      'Telefon: 0 (212) 285 66 77  <br> '+
      ' Tel: 0 212 440 00 00<br> '+
      'Faks: 0 212 440 00 10<br>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString3
  });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
    infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
  });

//4. Marker için Bilgi Penceresi 
    var contentString4 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
       '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Marmara Üniversitesi Göztepe Kampüsü</b> <br>'+      
      'Eğitim Mh. <br>'+
      'Kadıköy - İstanbul, 34722   <br> '+
      'Telefon:(0216) 414 0545<br> '+
      '<br>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString4
  });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function() {
    infowindow4.open(map,marker4);
  });

 // Polylines başlangıç 
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.98696866267149,29.052727818489075),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.16973837959339,29.561526775360107),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.106438353246574,29.023251682519913),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.01275461356736,28.9611903950572),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.98696866267149,29.052727818489075)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeOpacity:1.5,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
//Polylines bitiş 


  // Rectangle  Başlangıç 
   var infoWindow2;
 var rectangle;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(41.00697765211052,28.991975784301758),
      new google.maps.LatLng(41.00697765211052,28.991975784301758));
 rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });
 rectangle.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'bounds_changed', showNewRect);
  infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function showNewRect(event) {
  var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
  var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();

  var contentString = '<b>Koordinat Bulucu .</b><br>' +
      'Kuzey Dogu Kose Koordinatlari : ' + ne.lat() + ', ' + ne.lng() + '<br>' +
      'Yeni Guney Bati Kosesi : ' + sw.lat() + ', ' + sw.lng();

  infoWindow2.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow2.setPosition(ne);

  infoWindow2.open(map);
}
   // Rectangle Bitiş. 

   // Pembe Üçgen 
   var blueCoords = [
       new google.maps.LatLng(40.96045610668445,29.050426483154297),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.01275461356736,28.9611903950572),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.95008471741818,28.910694122314453)
  ];
  new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: blueCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF33FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF33FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    draggable: true,
    geodesic: false
  });

  // Boğaziçi Köprüsü Simgesi Animasyon 
   var lineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.09073722135943,29.053752422332764),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.091416441697305, 29.068644046783447)
  ];

  var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 5,
    strokeColor: '#9900CC'
  };

  line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: lineCoordinates,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: '100%'
    }],
    map: map
  });

  animateCircle();
}

function animateCircle() {
    var count = 0;
    window.setInterval(function() {
      count = (count + 1) % 200;

      var icons = line.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
      line.set('icons', icons);
  }, 5);
   // animasyon bitimi 

    // Transit Layer 
var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
  transitLayer.setMap(map);


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id ="panel">
    <input type="button" value="Traffic Layer ON " onclick=";"></input>
   <input type="button" value="Traffic Layer OF " onclick=";"></input>
   </div>


    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Layer inside initialize by using the var-keyword the Layer will not be accessible from outside of this function(what is the case when you apply the click-function via the onclick-property).

Add the click-listener inside initialize, after creating the Layer.

Sample-code(you may remove the `#panel`, the Control will be created on  the fly, furthermore there will be only 1 button with changing value depending on the state of the Layer, because there is no need for a OFF-button when the Layer is already OFF...and vice versa):

```
var trafficLayer  = new google.maps.TrafficLayer(),
    trafficCtrl   = document.createElement('div'),
    trafficBtn    = trafficCtrl.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));

    trafficBtn.type = 'button';
    trafficCtrl.style.cssText  = 'background:#fff;padding:5px';

    //click-listener for the button
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(trafficBtn,'click',function(){
      trafficLayer.setMap((trafficLayer.getMap())?null:map);
    });

    //observe the map-property of the TrafficLayer to get always the
    //correct state for the button 
    google.maps.event.addListener(trafficLayer,'map_changed',function(){     
      trafficBtn.value='Traffic Layer '+((!!this.getMap())?'OFF':'ON');
    });

    //trigger the map_changed-event to initialize the state of the button
    google.maps.event.trigger(trafficLayer,'map_changed',{});

    //add the control
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(trafficCtrl);
```

Add this code to the end of `initialize`.

**Note:** as it seems there is no traffic-data available for Istanbul, you'll need to zoom-out to see traffic-data for other  regions